# The error of Use of undeclared type 'CustomObject' in swift - ios

Tags: ios, swift

I have this custom object in group called madel

```
import Foundation
public class CustomObject
{
  var Id:Int!
  init(id: Int){
    self.Id = id
  }
  var description: String {
    return "{ID=\(Id)}"
  }
}
```

in another file, I have this struct, my purpose is to have a static list that can be modified or accessed from anywhere in the app:

```
struct Statics {
  static var listOfCustoms:[CustomObject] = []
}
```

I got this error : 
[image: error]

this is the whole error:

[image: Error]

Both files are added to the list of *Compile Sources* in the *Build Phases*

Comment: Have you imported CustomObject in Globals.swift?

Comment: another error says No Such Module CusomObject @SanderSaelmans

Comment: There's no need to import swift files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works for me, try to clean the project.

Also check both files' Target membership that there's a checkmark in front of your target (your app name).

Comment: still getting the same error, can it be because i put CustomObject in Model group ?

Comment: Groups are just for your convenience. Try to create new project with only these two files, comment out all code what needs other files and look what will happen. If there will be no errors then your code is correct, but you should check both files's `Target membership` that there's checkmark in front of your target (your app name). Or maybe there's already a class named `CustomObject`.

So first of all - check if these two files will compile without other code.